# Can I skip pre-auth for some requests in AD FS Web Application Proxy?

Tags: proxy, sharepoint, adfs

I have two IIS applications with Windows Authentication. One SharePoint Server(SE) and a provider hosted app, which is a separate website that can access SharePoint via OAuth.

The app can send AJAX requests to SharePoint just fine when there is no proxy involved. But when we introduce AD FS WAP on both applications they fail, because the AJAX request is redirected to AD FS for authentication.

I want most requests to SharePoint to be pre-authenticated, but not requests to the REST API as these use OAuth instead.

Is it possible to define some kind of rule for what requests should or should not be pre-authenticated in AD FS WAP?